# Bandwidth monitoring indicator?

Tags: 12.04, indicator, monitoring, bandwidth, network-monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)

Is there an app for bandwidth monitoring indicator particularly that be placed on the top panel for Unity? Something similar to System Monitor > Resources > Receiving and Sending?

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/40019/18887) at [What application indicators are available?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)